# Getting corresponding variable name in a foreach loop in R

Tags: r

If I have 4 different variables (`V1, V2, V3, V4`) and I want to easily iterate over them, one method I could use is `for(var in c(V1, V2, V3, V4))`. Is there any way I can apply a function to `var` that returns which variable it represents? For example, calling this function `f`, the code

```
for(var in c(V1, V2, V3, V4))
  print(f(var))
```

should print `V1V2V3V4`.

It doesn't seem likely that such a function exists, but I am hoping that someone here as a definite answer.

Comment: Does rownames() / colnames() work in your particular case?  You might have to reconstrue your for loop as a matrix operation, but that seems more r-like anyway.

Comment: Is `c(V1, V2, V3, V4)` a named vector, i.e. myvec <- c( V1 = V1, V2 = V2, V3 = V3 ... ). In this case you could simply iterate over the `names`: `for(varn in names(myvec)){print(varn}`

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to things that actually apply to `var` itself at the same time. For example, consider `f <- function(V1 = w, V2 = x, V3 = y, V4 = z)`. If I wanted this function to print out the value of each argument followed by the name of the argument, what should I put in the for loop. For example, `f(1, 2, 3, 4) ` would output something like `V1:1, V2:2, V3:3, V4:4` (with less formatting).

Comment: @JonClaus Were any of the solutions helpful? Since you are realtively new here you might want to read [**the about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. I notice you have only ever cast one vote and only ever accepted one answer. S.O. is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark. You are under absolutely **no** obligation to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be after something like this:

```
f <- function( ... ){
  args <- all.vars(match.call())
  x <- mget(args , envir = sys.frame())
  return( paste0( args , ": " , x ) )
}

V1 <- 1
V2 <- 2
V3 <- 3
f(V1 , V2 , V3)
# [1] "V1: 1" "V2: 2" "V3: 3"
```

This extracts the names of the arguments from `match.call` as a character vector, then uses these names in `mget` to find the value attached to each name in the environment of the function and pastes the result together.

However, If you have a named list you can just use `sapply` with `USE.NAMES = TRUE` to loop across elements of the list and return a named vector as the result of applyig some function to each element of the list:

```
sapply( list( V1 = 1 , V2 = 2 , V3 = 3 , V4 = 4 ) , `^` , 2 )
#V1 V2 V3 V4 
# 1  4  9 16
```

In the example above we apply the power function `^` and also pass the additional argument `2`, i.e. `x^2` where `x` is each element in the list.

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this situation often.

My strategy is to iterate over the variable *NAMES* and then use `get`.

eg:

```
for(v in c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")){
   print(v)

  # then to operate on the variable
  var <- get(v)
}
```

an added bonus is you can kick the `for` loop and use a nice `lapply` instead:

```
lapply(c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),  print)


#- or -#

lapply(c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), function(v) {
  print(v)
  someActionOn(get(v)))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to group your vars into some sort of structure, say a list, and then loop through the elements of the list

```
v1=rnorm(1030)
v2=rnorm(1330)
v3=rnorm(130)
varlist=list(Vee1=v1,Bee2=v2,vi3=v3)

for(i in 1:length(varlist)) {  
   assign( paste( names(varlist)[i],
                  "meanish",
                  sep=""), 
           mean(varlist[[i]]))
 }
```

then look in `ls()` to see what you have.

Comment: If you group your elements into a list, you are *much* better off using `lapply` to loop through the elements of the list, except in cases where you really need to use `for` because of it's side-effects. In this example I really would use `sapply( varlist , mean , USE.NAMES = TRUE )`. This returns the means in a named vector.

Comment: @SimonO101, what side effects?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I just mean that when you call a function for something other than it's return value. When you use `for` it's often used to modify an existing object iteratively. e.g. instantiating an empty `data.frame` before a loop and using a loop to fill each row (something I would avoid, but one way a `for` loop is often used for it's side effects). Or the `assign` function would be another good example.